# When my app disconnects from remote Geth does it mean it lose whole sync information?

Tags: go-ethereum

My app interacts with remote Geth node through SSH. The first sended command was `geth --cache=1024` When the node was sending back some sync logging information, the connection has been lost. Then I make a new session and send `geth attach` and think the node is running still. However it returns error:

> Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix
>   /home/.../.ethereum/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory

Is it true geth deletes any sync files when it lose the current connection? And if it's false even, what happens when the Geth node terminates its running (for e.g. because of crash)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are SSH-ing to your remote machine and then starting up `geth --cache=1024` in the console, when your SSH connection drops out the `geth` command will terminate.

You can check if `geth` is still running by SSH-ing back to your machine and typing the command `ps -ef | grep geth`, for example:

```
Iota:ESE user$ ps -ef | grep geth
  501 37632   879   0  2:36pm ttys001    0:03.31 geth --rpc console
  501 37634  2685   0  2:36pm ttys002    0:00.01 grep geth
```

Once `geth` terminates, the `geth.ipc` file may be removed depending on whether the application terminates gracefully. This `geth.ipc` file is an interprocess communication pipe and not a regular file. Once `geth` terminates, the file may still remain on the file system, but other processes cannot communicate to `geth` using this pipe.

If `geth` terminates without gracefully shutting down, the blockchain data can sometimes (very seldom) be corrupted.

Following is a recipe if you want to keep `geth` running on your Ubuntu (assumed from your previous posts) machine. If you want to terminate this background `geth` process, use the command `killall -q --signal SIGINT geth`.

---

#### Recipe For Running `geth` Automatically On Startup

If you want `geth` to run on your remote machine all the time, here is a recipe, all to be done in the SSH session on your remote machine:

1. Create a directory for your logs - I'm using `$HOME/ethlogs`.

   ```
   user@RemoteMachine:~$ mkdir $HOME/ethlogs
   ```
2. Create a directory for your log archive - I'm using `$HOME/logarchive`.

   ```
   user@RemoteMachine:~$ mkdir $HOME/logarchive
   ```
3. Create the file `$HOME/bin/runGeth` with the following contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   # Kill geth gracefully
   killall -q --signal SIGINT geth
   # Wait for geth to be killed gracefully
   sleep 30
   # Kill viciously if geth is still running
   killall -q geth

   # Remove the IPC pipe file if it still exists
   rm $HOME/.ethereum/geth.ipc

   DATE=`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`
   # Save old log file into the log archive directory
   mv $HOME/ethlogs/geth.log $HOME/logarchive/geth.log_$DATE

   # Use 6 for full details
   VERBOSITY=3

   # Add your geth command line parameters below
   geth --cache=1024 --verbosity $VERBOSITY 2>> $HOME/ethlogs/geth.log &
   ```
4. Set the file's executable bit.

   ```
   chmod 700 $HOME/bin/runGeth
   ```
5. Log out and then log back in so your $HOME/bin path is activated if it has not already been done.
6. Run `geth`

   ```
   user@RemoteMachine:~$ runGeth
   ```
7. If you want `geth` to automatically start after you reboot your machine, add the `runGeth` command to your `/etc/rc.local` file.

   ```
   user@RemoteMachine:~$ sudo vi /etc/rc.local
   ```

   and add the following line before the `exit 0`:

   ```
   sudo -u {your username} /home/{your username}/bin/runGeth &
   ```

   Save and exit the file. Try restarting your computer and use `ps -ef | grep geth` to check if `geth` is running.